# Firebase cloud functions, getting data from fields

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a document "chats", where are fields with string key and timestamp value and Im trying to iterate through the fields and load the values and the keys into the array. Then a certain value in the field is being sent as notification via Firebase messaging. All of this is being triggered on the "chats" document change. I was trying so many combinations but none of them worked.

Here is the snippet:

```
class FieldLoad {
  constructor(timestamp, userUID) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.userUID = userUID;
  }
}

const {onDocumentUpdated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
initializeApp();

// ON DOCUMENT CHANGE FUNCTION
exports.messagesNotification = onDocumentUpdated(
    "collection_A/document_A/{collection_B}/chats",
    (change, context) => {
      const afterData = change.after.data();
      const loadArray = [];
      for (const field in afterData) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(afterData, field)) {
          const fieldValue = afterData[field];
          const fieldLoadInstance = new FieldLoad(fieldValue.timestamp, field);
          loadArray.push(fieldLoadInstance);
        }
      }
      const notificationBody =
      loadArray.length > 0 ? loadArray[0].userUID : "No data available";
      const message = {
        notification: {
          title: "Notification Title",
          body: notificationBody,
        },
        token: "<device-token>",
      };
      admin.messaging()
          .send(message)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("Notification sent successfully:", response);
            return null;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
            return null;
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise that becomes resolves after all the asynchronous work is complete.  Just calling then/catch isn't going to make any async calls block before the end of the functions.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) about this.

```
return admin.messaging().send()...
```